# Why does Wikipedia state that angular velocity is equal to angular frequency?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, angular-velocity

Isn't Wikipedia wrong?  At the Wikipedia article [Angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency) it says that angular frequency and angular velocity are equal.   But how on earth are they equal?  Angular velocity is changing all the time while angular frequency is a constant(at least if period is constant ).  The only case they might be equal is in constant velocity.

Even in circular motion , suppose it's not moving in constant velocity.   Why would they be equal?   Angular velocity is changing every second.  While angular frequency is just a constant.   If you have such a system the angular velocity would be d0/dt which is different every second.  While the angular frequency would be the repetitions per second multiplied by 2 pi.

Angular frequency is a one value every time.  And velocity you can't even say it's value because it's dependant on time.

I don't really understand the statement in Wikipedia which says both are equal.    Can you explain?

Edit: this is even more bizarre in harmonic non circular motions.   Suppose you have a pendulum oscillating.   Then the angular frequency would be a constant measure of an imaginary circle. While angular velocity would be defined as the derivative of the angle.    The two are certainly not equal.   One is a changing derivative and one is constant.    But even in circular non constant motions it doesn't make sense as explained above.

Comment: I am not sure angular frequency is a constant. If you look at a chirped laser pulse that you would obtain from non linear optical pulse generation system, you would see that the angular frequency is defined as a function of time

Comment: I do not understand.   Angular frequency is well defined as 2pif

Comment: *"Angular velocity is changing all the time while angular frequency is a constant."* - ???  Consider an ideal record player which 'spins' the LP at a constant 33 1/3 rpm.  The angular velocity of the LP is *constant* (as is the angular frequency). Now consider a non-ideal record player with non-zero [*wow* and *flutter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow_and_flutter_measurement) - neither the angular velocity nor the angular frequency is constant.

Comment: Related question by the OP:  [Is angular frequency the same as angular velocity or are they different?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409443/9887)

Comment: Related question by the OP:  [When the oscillator is a system with an angle can we define the angular frequency to be the radians per unit time covered by the system itself?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409588/9887)

Comment: Re Wikipedia:  Have you considered asking the primary contributors to the Wikipedia article about this in the article's [Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Angular_frequency) section?  If you think the article is in error, you are free to edit it (just be prepared to have your edits edited or removed - that's the Wikipedia way).

Comment: Alfred Centauri  What do you mean by 'consider '  ??? For sure they don't have to be constant.   But I am refuting the claim that they are equal.  If velocity is changing within a period while period is constant .  Angular frequency would be constant while angular velocity would change each second.   I do not understand the statement of them being equal.   Certainly not in oscillators nor in circles with a changing velocity.

Comment: The ??? refers to the unquestionably incorrect statement I quoted from your post.

Comment: What are you saying? ??

Comment: *"Angular velocity is changing all the time"* In what system? And angular velocity of what? You've linked to a Wikipedia article on a general concept but your earlier question focused on a specific system. I've added an answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409588/  to clarify what I mean by asking what is alleged to have an angular velocity.

Comment: Isn't it enough to show that the statement is wrong even once in order to refute it?    I wrote very clearly.  Be it a an oscillatory system or even a circular motion as long as the velocity is changing but period is constant.   Angular velocity (d0/dt) is defined on a specific given time because the rate of change can change each second.  While angular  frequency is defined by a constant period  (if period is constant ). Angular frequency is a one value for the whole system.   Angular velocity is a changing d0 /dt.  It's the derivative of a given time.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you’re getting tripped up on what is meant by “angular velocity”.  Fear not; it’s confusing!

Angular velocity is not, as you may perhaps be thinking, the instantaneous velocity of something revolving around. Rather, it is the rate of change of angle. In analogy to positional velocity, which is the time derivative of position ($dx/dt$), angular velocity is the time derivative of angle ($d\theta/dt$).  Thus, angular velocity has the same units and magnitude as angular frequency. But like positional velocity, angular velocity is a vector (defined with the right hand rule like angular momentum), denoting the “direction” of $d\theta/dt$.

Comment: I do not understand.   Of course it's the rate of change of an angle.   But what if the velocity isn't constant?   The rate of change would be different every second.  On the other hand if the period is constant the angular frequency would be constant.

Comment: @bilanush Yes, of course you can come up with idiosyncratic situations where angular velocity is modulated faster than the period such that the period remains constant. But then the instantaneous angular frequency would be modulated as well. Angular frequency is not simply the inverse period <-- that would be the average angular frequency, averaged over a period.

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand.   I understood that angular frequency is the average velocity in one period.  Because it doesn't care about a certain point of time it just calculates the frequency per cycles multipled by 2 pi. So by definition it must be some sort of an average of a given full circle.  So why does Wikipedia equate  between the two?  Do you mean that Wikipedia only meant that the average velocity in a cicle is equal to average frequency given by 2nd f?

Comment: @bilanush the average angular frequency can be related to inverse period, but the angular frequency itself is defined generally just as Wikipedia suggests: it’s the magnitude of the (possibly time-varying) angular velocity.

Comment: Gilbert  Ha now I start to understand something.   So what you are saying is that angular frequency  in definition isn't just defined as 2pi f,  but rather has a broader general definition which is d0/dt and this IS INDEED instantaneous.   But apart from that,  there is definition of the average frequency or velocity and for this alone 2pi f would be the equivalent of it.  It's stange that people write 2pi f= d0/dt.  It doesn't equal.  Only the average is equal.  I hope I am right?

Comment: @bilanush don’t get hung up on what people write. The *vast* majority of the time you’re talking about simple harmonic motion, for which everything is simple and angular velocity is constant.

Comment: @bilanush and I should mention that in general angular velocity and angular are arbitrary functions of time, so saying that average frequency is 2 pi / T, where T is the period, does not always make sense. Because T might not be well-defined in general.

Comment: In harmonic motion it's getting crazier.  Cuz sometimes the defined oscillator is a pendulum with an angle which its own velocity is called angular velocity.  Which had confused me even more.  I guess when you wrote it's constant you meant the frequency  (velocity ) defined by the sinus phase on an associate circle.

Comment: As for your second comment.   I guess I am not on your level to understand it or when it happens.   But the main thing I wanted to understand is, that the defined measure of 2pi f   ISN'T equal d0/dt because it's taking into account full circles for measure as opposed to instantaneous velocity.  Whatever what it is, it looks like some sort of an average per cycle.   Even if it's not so accurate,  or void of meaning in other contexts.    Correct me if I am wrong.   Gonna see it tomorrow as I go to sleep now.  Thanx a lot for your time.  You are the only one who understood my point :)) the!

Comment: @bilanush I think you understand. d0/dt can be anything, in general.  When it is time varying, you can still define d0/dt = 2pi f, it’s just that frequency would then be a function of time f(t). By the way, there’s nothing about Nature which says these definitions must be the way they are. You are free to make your own definitions, provided you communicate them clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it saying that they are equal; it states that angular velocity is a vector quantity, and that angular frequency is its magnitude.

> "Angular frequency [...] is the magnitude of the vector quantity angular velocity."

perhaps you're referring to the phrase that follows,

> "The term **angular frequency vector** is sometimes used as a synonym for the vector quantity angular velocity."

In which case the *vector* part of *angular frequency vector* is an important distinction to make, and why it can be used as synonym to angular velocity.

Comment: source of quotes is the article linked in question, consulted on June 1, 2018  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency

Comment: As far as I understand it . It sounds like the only difference is that one is a magnitude  and one is a vector.   I am not even seeing how one is the magnitude of the other?  They may have completely different magnitudes.    Suppose a circular motion in which the velocity is changing constantly but the period is always constant.    In what sense can you claim one being the magnitude of the other?   Angular frequency would be a number  . And angular velocity would bexpect derivative of time.

Comment: Wikipedia here is being overly precise with the wording, imo... it's very typical for physicists to use the terms angular frequency/velocity to refer to the same thing